# How does eventargs in the addEventListener() callback pass through bind()

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I don't see how the e argument is passed. I'm guessing that using bind() in the callback automatically adds the e argument to the last argument list. Is this a convention in JS? Thank you for your clarification

```
 const handleHover = function (e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('nav__link')) {
        const link = e.target;
        const siblings = link.closest('.nav').querySelectorAll('.nav__link');
    const logo = link.closest('.nav').querySelector('img');
 
  }
};

nav.addEventListener('mouseover', handleHover.bind(0.5));
```

Comment: `In the following code`  - there is no code, only an image - you're using bind wrong - no, wait ... i see what that would do - the first argument to `bind` is the `this` for the function ... in this case, `this` will be the `Number(0.5)` - so, no matter how that handler is called - `this` will be `Number(5)` and whatever arguments will be whatever arguments are used to call the function - in this case, it's the `event`

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry, this is my first time to use StackOverflow to ask questions, I have modified the format, thanks for your prompt

Comment: No problem. Thanks for editing so quickly. If you don't mind adding your HTML, then the code is complete and runnable and you can turn it into a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do?noredirect=1&lq=1), making it really easy to help.

Comment: `.bind` return a new function with `this` binded. Event is passed internally.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, `addEventlistener` calls your callback function (`handleHover` in your case), with an `event` object.

Imagine that somewhere inside `addEventlistener` this exists:
`callback(event)`.

And in your case, you are handling this event with the `e` parameter.

Regarding `bind(0.5)` - this just sets `this` to be 0.5 in your `handleHover` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand what you mean.